# How much variation is necessary for regression analysis

Tags: regression

Let's say that I'm trying to find the factors which help predict whether I wear red shoes or not during a year long time-period. I could look at weather, day of the week, month, and other factors. However, how much variation does there need to be in the dependent variable for me to be certain that I am acctually measuring something that is meaningful. Do I need to have worn red shoes 2 times? 5? 50? 100? etc?

Basically, how much variation in the dependent variable is necessary to develop a statistical model that generates somewhat meaningful results?

Let's say that I have 150,000 rows and I am trying to explain variation that comprises 3.2% of that data. Is that enough?

Comment: Note that you'd probably be more interested in logistic or probit regression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be equating level of variation with sample size, and that is worth looking at more closely.  But a common approach is to define "meaningful" in terms both of an effect size (e.g., an r-squared of .032) AND a specific level of statistical significance (e.g., an alpha of .001).  "I'll call my result meaningful if it explains at least 3.2% of the variance in my outcome in a way that is significant at the .001 level."  Then it becomes a straightforward matter of calculation to determine the sample size necessary to achieve a certain level of power (ability to demonstrate a statistically significant effect if one exists).  The open-source program GPower is effective for using this type of approach across many different statistical procedures.

Comment: +1 rolando2 is right that what constitutes a 'meaningful' result is a theoretical question for the researcher, not a statistical question for the analyst.  In light of his comments about power, note that the further you get away from 50%, the more data are necessary to clearly resolve the relationship--rare phenomena are simply hard to study.  Furthermore, the problems of low probabilities are compounded by the existence of many predictor variables.  (Although, 150,000 observations is likely to be more than enough.)